# Import uncompressed video from MiniDV into Windows?

Tags: windows, video-capture, mini-dv

How can I import video from a MiniDV player in uncompressed format to Windows?  Once it's imported, will the file be viewable in both Windows and Mac [using iMovie]?

If it matters, I'm using a JVC GR-DV500U MiniDV videocam.  It connects to Windows via Firewire.  In the past, I've tried Windows Movie Maker but if I recall correctly, it imported the video in WMV format.  I want uncompressed format.

Comment: Can you give us more specifics? What is that MiniDV player? How do you capture the videos currently? What have you already tried and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: I updated the question with more details.